# Why isn't a dataframe I read in responding to skip_cols parameter or the method pd.set_index()?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe i read in with

```
 energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skiprows = 16, 
 skip_footer = 38, skip_cols = 2)
 energy.set_index('Unnamed: 2')
```

and it returns the following dataframe(the first row isn't ideal but I can solve that later)

```
    Unnamed: 0   Unnamed: 1   Unnamed: 2   Energy Supply    Energy Supply per Capita
 0  NaN          NaN          NaN          Petajoules       Gigajoules
 1  NaN          Afghanistan  Afghanistan  321              10
 2  NaN          Albania      Albania      102              35
 3  NaN          Algeria      Algeria      1959             51
 4  NaN          Andorra      Andorra      9                121
 5  Nan          Angola       Angola       642              27
```

I expected a dataframe as follows, with ['Unnamed: 0'] and ['Unnamed :1']  omitted and ['Unnamed: 2'] set as the index, as shown below:

```
    Unnamed: 2   Energy Supply    Energy Supply per Capita
 0  NaN          Petajoules       Gigajoules
 1  Afghanistan  321              10
 2  Albania      102              35
 3  Algeria      1959             51
 4  Andorra      9                121
 5  Angola       642              27
```

but neither of those things occur(and when i omit the respective parameter and set_index it remains identical.  When I try executing the code with skip_cols or set_index() its again identical.  Why don't these two bits of code change anything for me?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you are setting the index at third line, you have to pass inplace flag as true

```
 energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skiprows = 16, 
 skip_footer = 38, skip_cols = 2)
 energy.set_index('Unnamed: 2', inplace=True) #Here pass inplace flag
```

So that index is set on the orignal data frame not on the copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the `skip_cols` paramter isn't working (using `pd.__version__ '0.23.0'`). You might try using the `usecols` parameter instead if you know the column ranges. You can also set the index column inside `pd.read_excel` like this:

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', usecols='C:E', index_col=0, skiprows=16, skip_footer=38)

print(energy)

            EnergySupply EnergySupplyperCapita
NaN           Petajoules            Gigajoules
Afghanistan          321                    10
Albania              102                    35
Algeria             1959                    51
Andorra                9                   121
Angola               642                    27
```